# Как добавить элемент в начало блока php?

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="all-posts">
    <?php
    $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `login` = '$login'"); 
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<div class="post">'.$rows['post'].'</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Это код вывода постов из базы данных на страницу, они добавляются в конец блока "all-posts", мне нужно чтобы новый элемент добавлялся в начало блока "all-posts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить в запрос сортировку по идентификатору в обратную сторону

```
ORDER BY id DESC
```

либо по дате, если она имеется.